# D3js: ":last is not a valid selector"?

Tags: d3.js

`d3.select('.activity:last')` and `d3.selectAll('.activity:last')` both fail. Meanwhile; `$('.activity:last')` works.

```js
d3.selectAll('.activity:last')
  .append('<div class="hook-table">Table comes here</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="activity"></div>
  <div class="activity"></div>
  <div class="activity"></div>
  <div class="activity"></div>
  <div class="activity"></div>
</div>
```

**Is there a D3 way to pass `:last` selector.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:last` is not a valid css selector. It works with jQuery because jquery has added support for this selector:

> :last is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/))

As D3 only contemplates valid CSS selector strings so `:last` won't work with D3.

Instead you'll require a bit more code to get the last element.

If your div is the last of of its siblings, then  you can use `:last-child`:

```js
d3.select(".container").select(".activity:last-child")
  .text("5: This div selected");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="activity"><p>1</p></div>
  <div class="activity"><p>2</p></div>
  <div class="activity"><p>3</p></div>
  <div class="activity"><p>4</p></div>
  <div class="activity"><p>5</p></div>
</div>
```

However, this won't work if you have another element below the last div. The above will select the div with class "activity" that is the last child of `.container` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child)).

For more complex structures, where the last div or element with class "activity" isn't the last sibling, you'll need to take a more complex approach.